# How to add validator to private network

Tags: eth-2.0, staking, validators, prysm, private-ethereum

I made a PoS private testnet with 2 machine(node) at the moment.
But I can't find any reference for staking, adding validators.

I saw some questions:[How to use prysm add validator for private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/158645/how-to-use-prysm-add-validator-for-private-network), [How to add new validators on ethereum private network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/149229/how-to-add-new-validators-on-ethereum-private-network)

Anyway those answer wasn't accepted, also not work for me.

Cause validator key generator like "staking-deposit-cli" doesn't support option for private network, They just have option for mainnet and some public testnet.

And as you know we need to use Launch pad to be a validator but I don't have kind of that.

So could you guys tell me about possibility of Adding Validator to my private network?

Or If you know that way to d that, could I get some hint of that....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, use ethereal github project, there's no option for private network but we can change some config code in the project.